# Testing USB peripheral on Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, usb, usb-otg

I have one tablet, OTG cable and one specific device that reads signals and send them over USB. Now I want to make application that reads data from this device. That device is based on FTDI chip.

In documentation there is stated that emulator does not support USB connections. 
So how to test and debug applications in this case? Copying .apk file every time to tablet is not solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can debug on your tablet just as you do with the emulator, unless there is no adb USB driver available for your device.

Guidance can be found here: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Comment: If I understand well I can connect this USB device directly on PC and test it directly from emulator?

Comment: No, the emulator cannot read any device connected to your PC. You would connect the device to your tablet, connect your tablet to your PC (install the adb driver as per the link) and test/debug using your tablet, not the emulator. BUT, as should have occurred to me before, you can't plug both the device and your PC into the tablet at the same time (there's only one socket). I don't know if that's possible with a splitter/hub of some sort.

Comment: Thanks!
I will try with hub because I've already tested with keyboard, mouse and barcode reader in the same time on one device.

Comment: You can switch device to adb over wi-fi and connect to it. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp